# SQL generated by Entity Framework 6 for Count()

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've been looking into some of the SQL generated by EF6 and not sure why the following C# doesn't generate something easier.

```
var db = new QueryContext();
db.Database.Log = (s) => Console.WriteLine(s);
var query = db.Set<Books>().AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
query.Count();
```

The query generated looks like this for queries against SQL Server 2016:

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Books] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

I'm wanting to capture the generated SQL and display back to the user. I'd be happy if it returned:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS [A1]
FROM [dbo].[Books]
```

Comment: Nothing you can do about it. It's just how EF generates SQL.